# How to properly return large data from a std::future in c++11

Tags: c++11, return-value-optimization, stdasync

I'm a bit puzzled what is the proper way to return large data from an async function in c++.

Take for example this code. It creates a large vector in a function and returns the allocated vector.

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include <future>
#include <vector>

using timepoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;

timepoint start_return;

std::vector< int > test_return_of_large_vector(void)
{
    std::vector< int > ret(100000000);
    start_return = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    return ret;                          // MOVE1
}


int main(void)
{

    timepoint start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto ret = test_return_of_large_vector();
    timepoint end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto dur_create_and_return = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start);
    auto dur_return_only = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start_return);

    std::cout << "create & return time : " << dur_create_and_return.count() << "ms\n";
    std::cout << "return time : " << dur_return_only.count() << "ms\n";

    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, test_return_of_large_vector);
    sleep(3); // wait long enough for the future to finish its work

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    ret = future.get();                  // MOVE2
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // mind that the roles of start and start_return have changed
    dur_return_only = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start);
    dur_create_and_return = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start_return);

    std::cout << "duration since future finished: " << dur_create_and_return.count() << "ms\n";
    std::cout << "return time from future: " << dur_return_only.count() << "ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For me this prints

```
create & return time : 543ms
return time : 0ms
duration since future finished: 2506ms
return time from future: 14ms
//                      ^^^^^^
```

So apparently, when calling the function in the main thread, return value elision or moving is done. But the return value from the future is apparently copied around. Also, when trying to `std::move` in the lines marked by `MOVE[1,2]`, the return time from the `future.get()` call stays the same. On the other hand, when returning a pointer this the return time from `future.get()` is negligible (0ms for me).

So must large data be returned from futures via a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are *assigning* to `ret`, which already holds the result of your first call to `test_return_of_large_vector`. At minimum, then, your code will need to free `100000000 * sizeof int` bytes; the move-assignment of `vector::operator=(vector&&)` is specified to be of constant complexity (for appropriate allocators), but the destructor of the move source will take time.

If you call `ret.clear(); ret.shrink_to_fit();` first then "return time from future" comes down to 0ms ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fad4782f456b736)).

Alternatively you could just move-construct a different variable:

```
auto ret2 = future.get();                  // MOVE2
```

Comment: @PSIAlt `future.get` returns `T &` only for the `T &` partial specialization. For the generic specialization it returns `T`, which as a prvalue binds to rvalue references. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get

Comment: Or, in short, the OP profiled two different operations, and blamed the difference on something that wasn't different.